# Converting base64 to blob in javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, html, cordova, canvas

I tried to convert a JPEG's base64 string to a blob on a Cordova/hybrid app running on iOS 8 using the following function `b64toBlob`.

```
b64toBlob = function(b64, onsuccess, onerror) {
    var img = new Image();

    img.onerror = onerror;

    img.onload = function onload() {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;

        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        canvas.toBlob(onsuccess);
    };

    img.src = b64;
}
```

However it's giving an error

```
Uncaught Error: TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'canvas.toBlob(onsuccess)')
```

when we do

```
var imageData = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData

b64toBlob(imageData,
    function(imageBlob) {
       uploadBlob(imageBlob)
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    });
```

How can be work around this error?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try this out.  Please note that `dataURI` is assumed to include base64 prefix. (e.g. `"data:image/jpeg;base64,"`)

```
function b64toBlob(dataURI) {
    
    var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
    
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return new Blob([ab], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
}
```

Usage:

```
...

var blob = b64toBlob(imageData);

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("source", blob);
...
```

Comment: I tried your function and got the error `Uncaught Error: InvalidCharacterError: DOM Exception 5: An invalid or illegal character was specified, such as in an XML name`. Any ideas?

Comment: I copied the dataURI string to https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/5440ebd3ae72708a651b/raw/273d48f0904b58c35364d422675d8d332023f1cf/gistfile1.txt

Comment: dataURI string should include base64 header, something like "data:image/jpeg;base64,"  Please let me know how it goes with it. @Nyxynyx

Answer (score 6):

```
  fetch("data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64Data)
    .then(res => res.blob())
    .then(blob => {
      console.log(blob);
      var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    });
```

Comment: I get "Network request failed" when I try this.

Answer (score 3):

In short, you can use the following function but if you want more details about this, you can read this post [Create a blob from base64 data](https://catchy-code.com/2018/07/04/create-a-blob-from-base64-data/)

```js
const b64toBlob = (b64Data, contentType='', sliceSize=512) => {
    const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
    const byteArrays = [];
 
    for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
        const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
 
        const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
        for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
        }
 
        const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
 
        byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }
 
    const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
    return blob;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Please try this simple way**

```
  fetch(base64).then(res => return res.blob()).then(blob => console.log(blob));
```

Comment: fetch with base64 working for iOS device but not working for android!
have you any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. The reason for me is that there is space in the base64 string.
`base64Str = base64Str.replace(/\s/g, '')`

This solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

```
const loadedPreviev = "data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKJeLjz9MKMS..."
const base64Response = await fetch(loadedPreview)
const newBlob = await base64Response.blob()
```

Comment: I found info what helped me here https://splunktool.com/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript