# Angular 4 Download array of base64 images as ZIP file

Tags: angular, image, typescript, download, zip

I'm working in a Angular2 v4 app with Typescript and I need a way to download many images (in base64 format) into a Zip file.

For example:
I have an array like this (fake base64 images just for example)

```
data = [
  'data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA ...',
  'data:image/png;base64, iVBTYu0KGgoBBBBNSUhYUgJJJJUA ...',
  'data:image/png;base64, CGBHHFGY0goAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA ...',
  ...
]
```

I need a way to download it converting each image to a .jpg or .png image first and then compile all images and dowload as a zip file. Something like this (I dont know the code, I just need something like this)

```
downloadZip() {
  const arrayAsJPG = [];
  this.data.forEach(i => {
    const imageInJpg = i.convertToJPGfile(); // this is not code, this is a function that converts the base64 to a jpg file
    arrayAsJPG.push(imageInJpg);
  });
  ZipFileSaver.save(arrayAsJPG, 'myImageReport.zip'); // this isn't code neither, just and interpretation of what I need

}
```

There is any way to make that?

Comment: In the browser or in a node.js based server function called from your Angular app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@gary gave a good explanation.
I found a few examples on stackoverflow:

[Is it possible to generate zip file and download in Angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51099549/is-it-possible-to-generate-zip-file-and-download-in-angular-4)

[Converting base64 to blob in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27980612/converting-base64-to-blob-in-javascript)
Can also use `@types/jszip`.

I builded an example that does the following:

- It get the array as you described from an API (mock);
- It convert each item of that array to an blob;
- It add the blob as a file to the zip file;
- And last create the zip file;
- I only had png base64 so change that to jpg.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jzqtrk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably need to do this on a server in Node.

You have two questions here:

**To convert the data string to an image**

This is tough in the browser.  You can render the data string as an img tag src and trigger a download of the image via javascript.  I don't think you can write it to disk in the browser though so that a zip file utility can use it.  This would be trivial in Node though.

**To create a zip file**

You should use an NPM package.  Most are geared toward Node. You might have luck creating zip files directly in the browser using something like [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/).  Search Google for "npm zip" to see many other packages.

Comment: The example provided on the JSZip homepage linked includes taking an image in base64 representation (in this case a gif), and adding it to a zip file. I'd suggest following that pattern. You should be able to use this library either client or server side, as your requirements dictate

Comment: Unless the file is immense or requires a lot of processing before download, it should be perfectly fine to convert it into a zip file in the browser. JSZip just converts string buffers to a different format, so it should be equally trivial in the browser.